# TouchableHighlight OnPress is not calling a function

Tags: react-native

I'm making an app in React Native and i have a problem that i don't understand.

In fact, when i press a button of my list, the onPress property related to this button don't call my function.

```
_onPressButton=() => {
   Alert.alert("Lol");
}

_renderRow (rowData, sectionID) {
return (
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.row} onPress={() => this._onPressButton}>
    <Text style={styles.boldLabel}>{rowData.name}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.label}>{rowData.art}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)
}
```

This two functions are in my class, outside the render(). There is the render :

```
render () {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ListView
      renderSectionHeader={this._renderHeader}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.listContent}
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this._renderRow}
      renderFooter={this._renderFooter}
      enableEmptySections
      pageSize={15}
    />
  </View>
  )
 }
}
```

So when I press my button, nothing happens :/. Is someone have an idea please?
Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not invoked the _onPressButton function.
You can just pass this function on the onPress handler without using the arrow function, like this:

```
 onPress={this._onPressButton}
```

If you want to pass any parameters then you can wrap it around an arrow function.

```
onPress={() => {this._onPressButton('someParams')}}
```

P.S Your current code calls the onPress handler but does not invoke your _onPressButton function

```
 onPress={() => {this._onPressButton}} // _onPressButton is not invoked 
 you have to invoke it as:

 {() => {this._onPressButton()}}
```

Comment: Yeah it helps thanks ! But apparently i had to write renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)} in the render. Do you know why?

Comment: When calling it from jsx, the context of "this" keyword is lost, so you have to bind it.
I would suggest binding the function in the constructor
       this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this);

or using the arrow function like you did with _onPressButton.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way is to have both `renderRow`& `onRowPress` both binded on 
**constructor** like this:

```
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this)
    this.onRowPress = this.onRowPress.bind(this)

  }
```

Then on `renderRow`

```
  renderRow (rowData) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onRowPress(rowData)} >

      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
```